# NPM Install Error "MODULE_NOT_FOUND" & NPM Occuring Throw Error

Tags: npm

I just installed node module through the NPM,whenever i try to install somthing with npm, it throws the following error. I think this problem like a permission issue, But  This  is not looks like a permission issue. What is the problem? I want to execute command(npm install ) without throw error.

```
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /home/david/NodeJS/public_html
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/david/NodeJS/public_html/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Is there anything interesting in `/home/david/NodeJS/public_html/npm-debug.log`?

Comment: Following Log, 
4 error Error: Cannot find module 'github-url-from-username-repo'

Comment: I just re-installed NPM, it is working, but I can't Understand 'npm ERR!'  as ever.